# soapUI: Revalidate (recorded) Request/Response pair

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

Is there a way to record a response (even non permanently during one "test-session") in a way that I can use an assertion like "please validate that the (new) response is exactly like this (old recorded) one".
The use case is a regression test for changes which apply to several web services, which then have to be retested to be sure there were no side-effects.

Comment: It can be so easy, with soapUI Pro (but a little more uncomfortable with the free version as well), you can just choose (context menu) "Add Assertion ... for Content" on the root element (env:Envelope) of the response in the "Outline" view/tab.
Obviously, data might change quite often (eg. when dates are involved), but in the assertion it is even possible to identify the failing element (xmlunit is used for comparison).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that, after the Web service is changed, the old response will be available to your test only as a saved XML file or log file.

I'm also assuming that you have the free version of SoapUI.

How good is your Groovy? There might be a way, if you copied and pasted the old response into an XML file, for you to read in that XML file in a Groovy script assertion or Groovy script step. This part might also be done by creating a Groovy class from the XML and making sure that the class is in SoapUI's classpath.

Within that Groovy assertion or step, you would create a new XMLSlurper object from the XML in that file (or by referencing the class) and compare the values in the XMLSlurper object to the values in your new response.

Caveat: I haven't tried this myself but it's the first thing that comes to my mind if you won't be able to get the old response any other way and you're working with the free version.

Comment: yes, I assume this would be possible, but the comparison could be quite challenging. However, it is also the only way I can think of (but I would add a step XMLSlurper -> XMLUnit, because comparison would be much easier and verbose).